How to disable write protection on EEPROM?
I have been trying to program M95160 2 kbyte EEPROM. There is an address and corresponding data - the programmer takes care of everything else so that part is all fine.
However I'm not sure about how to realise a PCB implementation. The difficulty for me is how to deal with the write protection facility this IC has.
At the moment pins 3, 7 and 8 are held high, 4 ground, the rest to appropriate functions clock, data, output and chip select.
Will the write protect be disabled as I have connected it?


That should be explained on the data sheet.

Add a link to the datasheet in your question - not in the comments.

That link seems to be to your own computer. You need to link to a publicly accessible site, preferably that of the manufacturer.

As stated in the comments, the answer is on the datasheet (page 15). Section 5.5 Data protection and protocol control:

